# Heroku não funciona depois de adicionar o dependencias no pom.xml (Maven)

Tags: java-ee, maven, tomcat, heroku

Fiz o deploy de um projeto java com maven, funcionou tranquilo, porém depois que coloquei as dependências  no arquivo pom.xml e dei o push, o heroku não executa mais, nem mesmo o "hello world". Segue como estava o pom.xml, depois como ficou após adicionar as dependências:

Como estava o arquivo pom.xml (Que funcionou):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

     <groupId>com.app</groupId>
     <artifactId>apiexpotaxi</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>war</packaging>

     <name>apiexpotaxi</name>

     <properties>
         <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     </properties>

     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>javax</groupId>
             <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
             <version>7.0</version>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
     </dependencies>

     <build>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.1</version>
                 <configuration>
                     <source>1.7</source>
                     <target>1.7</target>
                     <compilerArguments>
                         <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                     </compilerArguments>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.3</version>
                 <configuration>
                     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.6</version>
                 <executions>
                     <execution>
                         <phase>package</phase>
                         <goals>
                             <goal>copy</goal>
                         </goals>
                         <configuration>
                             <artifactItems>
                                 <artifactItem>
                                     <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                     <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                     <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                     <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                 </artifactItem>
                             </artifactItems>
                         </configuration>
                     </execution>
                 </executions>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
    </build>

 </project>
```

Como o arquivo pom.xml ficou depois que adicionei as dependências:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>apiexpotaxi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>apiexpotaxi</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.caelum</groupId>
            <artifactId>vraptor</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Arquivo Procfile:

```
web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ? Será se o heroku está reconhecendo as dependências?